# CAN-bus: transmitted data gets corrupted

Tags: python, can-bus

Im working on transmitting various bodysignals via the can bus to monitor driver drowsiness.
Right now i'm encountering the following problems:

1. The signals of a message seem to get filled with 0's, where they should just be empty

For example: when sending a message, which is defined in a dbc-file like this

```
BO_ 515 C_Light: 8 Vector__XXX
 SG_ C_Lightmode : 4|3@1+ (1,0) [0|7] "" Vector__XXX
 SG_ C_Blinker : 1|2@1+ (1,0) [0|3] "" Vector__XXX
```

with the values 4 (100) and 3 (11) the transmitted value is 70 (110 0 11 0), which leads to he next problem.

2. Different signals of a message get merged into one

The added 0's result in ignored start bits of the signals it seems.

3. Signals longer than 8 bits get split

In other cases I need to send values higher than 255, therefor using 10 bit signal length. This results in 8 correctly sent, but wrong value bits and 2 bits, that get cut off and treated as a separat signal. For example 360 (101101000) is converted to 104 (1101000) followed by (the first two cut off bits) 2 (10).

Has anyone ever had similar problems and knows a way to fix them?

---

I'm using the following code to send the data:

```
can_telematics_bus = can.interface.Bus()
db1 = cantools.db.load_file('../dbc/AGL_Candb.dbc')

def write_Light(Lightmode, Blinker ):
    Light = db1.get_message_by_name('C_Light')
    Light_data = Light.encode({'C_Lightmode': Lightmode, 'C_Blinker': Blinker})
    Light_message = can.Message(arbitration_id=Light.frame_id, Light_data, is_extended_id= False)
    can_telematics_bus.send(Light_message)
```

My configuration:
Nvidia Jetson Nano with Python 3.6
python-can 3.3.4
cantools 31.1.0
Arduino Uno
CAN-Bus-Shield 1.0.0

Comment: Wait, are you saying this hobbyist stuff is actually going into a car? How do you plan to meet automotive standards and type approval with hobbyist PCBs?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? 1) this seems to be the correct encoding based on the DBC excerpt you show. There is a 1 in front and a 0 at the back, but those bits should not matter, as they are not used in the signals you show. 2) Which 0s are added and where? 3) Also that seems to be correct.

Comment: @Lundin I never mentioned that. Its only intended for simulation purposes and to test and validate various new techniques for drowsinessdetection. But thanks for your concern.

Comment: @Lundin My question was not directed to you, I was just trying to help OP. I fully agree to your concerns, but I think it is still ok, to help hobbyists to dig into those topics (while making sure they know the risks).

Comment: @M.Spiller I apologize, I must have gotten your comment mixed up with the one from  nepho5 that pinged me with a notification.